# when using expressions like "right wing populism", can we use the preposition 'in' before it?

Tags: prepositions

> The 21st century saw the steady rise of right-wing populism, anti-elitism, and neo-nationalism and social conservatism.

What I wish to say is that these trends emerged much earlier, but have intensified in the last few decades.
Should I use rise in right-wing populism or rise of in this case?
regards.

Comment: It might be more useful to think in terms of "Can we use "in" to create a prepositional modifier *after* the noun *rise*?"

Comment: It's essentially a stylistic choice, but *the rise **in** X* implies *X **already existed** [before gaining even more traction]*, whereas *the rise **of** populism* tends to imply both ***initial arrival** and **rapid increase***. Note that [*the rise **of** populism* is some 20 times more common than *the rise **in** populism*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+rise+of+populism%2Cthe+rise+in+populism&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)